# React. <h1> with text in border

Tags: reactjs

Now I see an h6 (Click here) over my Title but I want to see it such us the image below.
I don't know the name of the "text in the border of my title".

```
function useHover(){
  const ref = useRef()
  const [hovered,setHovered] = useState(false)

  const enter = () =>setHovered(true)
  const leave = () =>setHovered(false)

  useEffect(()=>{
    ref.current.addEventListener("mouseenter",enter)
    ref.current.addEventListener("mouseleave",leave)
    return () =>{
      ref.current.removeEventListener("mouseenter",enter)
      ref.current.removeEventListener("mouseleave",leave)
    }
  },[ref])
  return [ref,hovered]
}


return (
    <div >
      <Link to="/Something">
        {hovered && <h6>Click here</h6>}
        <h1  ref={ref}>Title</h1>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
```

[image: I would the right thing when the mouse is over title.]

Comment: material ui calls the `text` a label https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#textfield

Comment: do you just want to know the name? or your code isn't working as you expected

Comment: I want know the name and how it must be applied in my program. 
Now I see TextField but how could I use it in my code?

Comment: you should install material ui https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/ then using the link I sent previously look at the code and use the one that best suits you. It's pretty simple and intuitive